# Where is the dividing line (mount point) of the two iOS partitions?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I know that iOS has two partitions, but I've never found anywhere that gives clues as to where they split. Is one partition on `/` and the other on `/var/mobile/`, or are all the user profiles (`/var/root/`, `/var/wireless/`, etc) on the second partition (at `/var`)? Is it possible to resize these partitions? On the same note, is `/var` a symbolic link to `/private/var/` or is it the other way around?

Comment: /var is a symlink to /private/var (same in OS X). As is /etc a symlink to /private/etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/` is the mount point for `/dev/disk0s1s1`; `/private/var` is the mount point for `/dev/disk0s1s2`.

[image: Cydia's storage info]

**disk0s1s1** is reserved for iOS system files. It is equivalent to OS X's /System and /Library directories. It is the smaller of the two partitions (the size can be set using Redsn0w or Sn0wbreeze during the jailbreak process). The default size is set to 1 GB for iOS 5 and around 600-700 MB in previous versions.

**disk0s1s2** is reserved (as of iOS 1.1.3) for user data (3rd party applications, music, photos, etc.). It is the larger of the two and varies depending on the flash memory available (which is dependent on the device purchased).

The layout of the disk is stored in `/etc/fstab`, which is also used by jailbreak tools to make the system partition writable.

- Source: [iOS Forensic Analysis](http://books.google.ca/books?id=XYHMwVYZ3lsC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=ios%20/dev/disk0s2&source=bl&ots=ZVkinCBY_s&sig=MJFsXyzQimqVcQ9YF_P44ZkpAjE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Xr5qT8O_N5DKiAKB66i8BQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=ios%20/dev/disk0s2&f=false)
- Additional reading: [The iPhone Wiki](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=/)

Answer (score 3):

One partition is mounted as "/" and contains OS, basic apps and firmware upgrades.
The other is mounted as "/private/var" and contains pretty much everything else (apps, iPhoto data, SMS etc.).

Why would you want to resize these partitions? I don't believe it is possible.

Comment: I've heard that they get resized during the JailBreaking process, and I seem to run out of space quickly on the Syetem partition. If they could be resized, I could install more tweaks and system applications.

Comment: Are there any references you could give in your answer? Does the "Storage: ---MB on / ----MB on /var" information in SBSettings have anything to do with the partitions?

Comment: Sorry I don't know SBSettings - I don't jailbreak. My information comes from the two books I know on iPhone Forensics, there is one by Jonathan A. Zdziarski (published 2008) and one by Andrew Hoog and Katie Strzempka (published 2011). There's another by Sean Morrissey (published 2010) but I don't have it.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson Yes, the values in SBSettings reflect how much space is used/remaining in each partition.