# IPhone 4S IOS 9.1 Storage Issue!

Tags: ios, storage

I have an iPhone 4S 8GB with 9.1 installed and it says 5.3GB capacity with 4.5 GB available. I feel so hopeless and I've searched everyone online. Here's the deal.. I don't have anything installed and it use to say 4.8GB but it got low for no reason after I went back into settings to re check the storage. How does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

My 16GB iPhone 5s reports 12.2GB capacity on iOS 9. It's normal to only have 5.3GB of capacity for an 8GB device. First, this is because iOS takes up quite a bit of room ([and steals a little extra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45123/where-is-the-dividing-line-mount-point-of-the-two-ios-partitions), too, just in case). Second, when calculating storage, 1GB is equal to 2<sup>30</sup> (1,073,741,824) bytes, but Apple sells you the iPhone with 1GB defined as only 10<sup>9</sup> (1,000,000,000) bytes (this is usually noted on the side of the iPhone box).

Comment: Again, Is it normal for an IPhone 4s to come with 4.8 gb out of box with no apps installed?

Comment: Yes, it is normal.